# Where can I find more details about rasterFunctions?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, image-service

I have published an Image service with ArcGIS Server 10, containing the results of an interpolation operation. The Image which is returned from the service is in greyscale.

I wish to render it with a stretched color ramp, with the following properties:
[image]

The RestEnd Point API, mentions that a [rasterFunctions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/index.html?israsterfunctions.html) Parameter has to be given as a renderingRule, for the [Export Image Operation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/exportimage.html). The given samples for the rasterFunctions are very limited, And I haven't been able to create a rasterFunctions which causes any noticeable change in the exported output.

Where can I find more details about rasterFunctions? Or build the rasterFunctions Object to get the same result as shown in the window?

Answer (score 1):

This is the main ESRI page

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/creating-custom-raster-functions.htm

And this is a Github page with more info

https://github.com/Esri/raster-functions