# Where can I find geodata for the Russian терсон-мо or терсон-ате census units? Or: can osm_admin polygons be linked to those?

Tags: openstreetmap, statistics, census, data, russia

I'm looking to combine [Russian census data](http://std.gmcrosstata.ru/webapi/) with georeferenced polygons.

This is for a research project looking into different aspects of mobility within the Republic of Саха (Sakha/Yakutsk), the data available via [GADM](http://gadm.org) is not sufficient (Note that the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60090/where-can-i-find-more-details-about-rasterfunctions) indirectly refers to GADM data and thus does not answer my question)

The problem is that I am not able to find any kind of geodata – be it either a download from the Russian Census Office or any place to purchase it.

On the other hand, the *administrative boundary* polygons in OpenStreetMap seem to represent at least in parts the same entities. Unfortunately, the tags do feature neither терсон nor окато ids, and the place names do not match up either (I also tried a similarity comparison using a Levenshtein algorithmus which did not yield any but a few matches).

**Can anybody with a better command of the Russian or Yakutian language and more experience with Russian census data point me into the right direction to where to obtain терсон polygon data or link OSM data to терсон ids?**
We do have some budget for geodata and local project partners (who unfortunately don't have any experience with statistical or geographical data), so purchasing the data, also from within a Russian academic institution, might be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I could see, you could crossreferene osm data with `терсон` names.

For instance:
`Верхнеколымский улус` from http://std.gmcrosstata.ru 
matches with 
http://atd.osm.rambler.ru/r1399830.html
and there are OSM Relation/Way ids for nested territories. That's the id of `Верхнеколымский улус` http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1399830 (you could find it on list of Saha (Yakutia) nested territories http://atd.osm.rambler.ru/r151234.html )

There are also some additional info like `Код ОКТМО` thats ids of territories accordingly to national territory classificator.

Also there are ESRI Shapes for Yakutia, here http://beryllium.gis-lab.info/project/osmshp/ description of data: http://gis-lab.info/qa/osmshp.html

So you could match names with polygons using name field from shapes.

Also

You could ask NextGIS http://nextgis.ru/ for help for money. (The have made some projects with Russian open data combined with OSM data).

You could ask me directly via e-mail (it's in my profile). I am native Russian OSM geek.

You could ask Russian OSM community here:
http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewforum.php?id=21

Comment: thanks for the hints – I actually already tried to link osm polygons to terson polygons via their names – but that didn't prove successful (not even employing a levenshtein similarity measure to compare the two). Maybe I'm doing something wrong – I'm taking you on that offer and send you an e-mail with details about my attempt, maybe you can find the flaw

Comment: @christoph I didn't receive your's mail.

Comment: didn't yet send it, because I'm still running some statistics to see how many of the polygons, how much of the area and population i can grasp already – also am repeating the whole thing for the entire russian federation, the levenshtein algorithmus takes a while ;)